# How to compare V8 Javascript Engine version between Chrome and NodeJS in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, google-chrome, nodejs, javascript

Every time that a feature of ECMAscript specification is implemented (see link below) in **V8 Javascript Engine** from **Google Chrome browser** we are never know when will be available on **NodeJS Server**. I always wanted a simple way to find out that information typing into Terminal on Bash command line (CLI).

**ECMAScript Compatibility Table**:

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Well, now I would like share it with you!

Comment: May be helpful for some people reaching this page via web search: https://v8.dev/docs/version-numbers which links to https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/ which has chrome --> v8 versions (but if you're not stuck in a cli, then chrome://version is best as mentioned in the accepted answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For check the current version installed of **Google Chrome browser**, **NodeJS Server** or **V8 Javascript Engine** from NodeJS, type into Terminal on Bash CLI:

```
$ 
$ google-chrome --product-version
  63.0.3239.84
$ 
$ node --version
  v8.9.3
$ 
$ node -p process.versions.v8
  6.1.534.48
$
```

No needs **Grep** or **AWK** or **Sed** to trimming the text resultant!

For check the version of **V8 Javascript Engine** from Chrome browser, type the URL `chrome://version` on Address bar.

For find out which Chrome version implemented each ECMAScript spec feature, access the site below and filter the category *Javascript*:

https://www.chromestatus.com/samples

For find out which V8 version came with past Chrome versions, access the site below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history